# Immigration : Australia passenger card - Migrating vs returning

Tags: australia

I'm French citizen with Australian permanent residency since 2018. When I was first awarded the residency, I entered the country within the first 5 months (as required) in order to validate this status.
But I did not permanently immigrate then. I went back home (in Spain) for 2 years.

I'm about to immigrate for good to Australia in the coming days. I know that before entering the country I have to fill a *Passenger card*, whose back is replicated below. I need to choose between two possible answer :

- A : Migrating permanently
- B : Resident returning

Which one should I select? I think that both can apply. I'm migrating permanently, but I'm also a resident returning to Australia.

Is there a big difference? 
Thanks

[image: Passenger card]

Comment: I don't know for sure. But if you pick migrating permanently, that affects your customs limits as you're allowed household goods/larger allowances. You might want to check that.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (although I can't back this up with sources) is that the final section of the card is for government/tourism statistics and does not really meaningfully impact the immigration proces.  (I still wouldn't recommend ticking "migrating permanently" if you're entering on a tourist visa.)

In your case, since you're coming for good and intend to stay in Australia, I would select "A: Migrating permanently".  I chose this myself when I moved back to Australia last year, despite also being a returning resident.